# Does tee forward data that has not made it into the file?

Tags: linux, bash, tee

I'm zeroing a new hard disk like so:

```
pv /dev/zero | tee /dev/sdb | sha1sum -
```

The idea is that I will zero the disk and simultaneously compute a checksum of however many zeros got written. Then I'll sha1sum the block device and see if it matches the data that I originally wrote to it.

The question is, what happens when "tee" runs out of space on the device and terminates? Say the block device is exactly 1 million bytes; tee will obviously fill it with 1 million zero bytes, but will it forward *exactly* 1 million zero bytes to sha1sum?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the original question:

No, `tee` will not stop writing to `stdout` at precisely the point at which a write to a file specified in an argument fails.

But I don't see that it matters much. It appears that your goal is to ensure that the entire disk has been overwritten with zeros, without worrying about how big the disk is. So reading the disk and comparing every block read to a block of zeros should suffice. You can do that with `cmp /dev/sdb /dev/zero`. If it says "EOF on /dev/sdb", then all the bytes were 0.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I thought of another way to do the same thing, albeit a little indirectly:

```
pv /dev/zero | dd bs=100M of=/dev/sdb 2> log
```

dd's report (captured in "log") should contain a precise count of bytes written, and you can use that to compute the sha1sum (or, alternatively, diff the block device against a generated stream of exactly that many zeros).

(bs=100M is because dd's default block size is 512 bytes, which turns out not to be performant in my use case)